# Move Google Contacts from One Group to Another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I am trying to write a Google Script that I can run regularly to move contacts added to a custom group by a third party tool and move them to My Contacts so they sync on iOS.

I am able to write a script to do it with a single contact as a test:

```
function myFunction() {

var contact = ContactsApp.getContact(‘EMAIL);
var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts');
group.addContact(contact)

}
```

However, when I try to start pulling in all contacts within a Contact Group and then update them I am running into errors.

```
function myFunction() {

var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Test Label');
var contacts = group.getContacts();
var group2 = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts');

group2.addContact(group)

}
```

I believe the issue is that `group.getContacts()` is returning an array and I can't simply add that to a Group but I can't figure out how to process each result from the array individually to move them.

Comment: When I try to add that for loop I get the error:

TypeError: group2.addcontact is not a function

Do I need to create a special function for moving the contact?

Comment: Update: it was just a capitalization issue needed `addContact`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

`addContact(contact)` accepts a single contact, so you would need to use for loop to add the contacts one by one.

```
for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  group2.addContact(contacts[i]);
}
```

**Reference:**

[Class | Contacts App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontacts)

[Class | Contact Group](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact-group#addContact(Contact))